# Convert list of dictionaries to: List of dictionaries whose values are lists of one

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list of dictionaries, e.g.,

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}]
```

... I would like to move each value in each dictionary into a list:

```
[{'a': [1], 'b': [2]}, {'c': [3], 'd': [4]}]
```

in a one-liner if practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a dict list `l` of dicts:
`[{k:[d[k]] for k in d} for d in l]`